# Forward declare in nested namespace

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a class (in a header file) that requires the following method:

```
static const foo::bar::clz* getSomething(void);
```

As I don't want to pollute the header file with an `#include` I choose to *forward declare* `clz`:

```
namespace foo
{
    namespace bar
    {
        class clz;
    }
}
```

But that's rather clumsy too. Is there a cuter way of doing this in C++11? Something along the lines of

```
class foo::bar::clz;
```

It would be nicer still if you didn't have to anticipate whether or not it's implemented as a `class`, `struct` or `union`. Have the C++11 grammarians covered that one too? (`typename auto` could be a candidate but I'm not an expert in C++ grammar).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nested namespaces can't be avoided.

As for `class` vs. `struct` vs. `union`, partially: `class` and `struct` can be used interchangeably. If it's a `union`, it must be declared as such.

Comment: But, you're prized with a warning when you forward-declare an object as `struct` and declare it as a `class` after.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster True, compilers usually warn about this. Nevertheless, it's legal and not (by itself) dangerous. The warning is probably justified as "are you sure you're referring to what you think you are?" It's one of those few I'd be willing to disable.

Comment: It can be dangerous, because of issues not covered by the standard, like name mangling ... at least on MSVC struct and class are mangled differently, so you will get linker errors if you get the forward declaration wrong

Comment: @FabioFracassi Well, this means MSVC is non-conforming in this aspect. The standard guarantees `class` and `struct` to be equivalent here (except for the default access control, of course).

Comment: For what it's worth, here's a (the?) bug report for MSVC's non-compliance.  It's been closed with 'as designed' http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/389738/class-vs-struct-in-forward-declaration-leads-to-linker-error